# Android Studio Application Running

Tags: android-studio

When I run a simple application it shows the following lines.
I don't know more about android application development.

```
pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapplication
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/134738/failure-installfailedinvalidapk

Issue will be your package name will be wrong. Change the package name to include atleast one . like xyz.myapplication.